# datetimepicker value is not binding to the property spring with thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf, datetimepicker

I am using `thymeleaf`, `Spring` and `jQuery`.

I have set model object in spring to eventCreate and the date property is `eventDate`. I am binding these in `thymeleaf` as below.

```
<form id="event-create" method="post"  th:action="@{/eventCreate/date}" th:object="${eventCreate}"> 

<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" placeholder="" th:field="*{eventDate}">
```

Using jQuery `datetimepicker` to select date and time of the event.

```
<script>
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                format: 'm/d/Y h:i A'
}); 
</script>
```

Using `dateTimePicker` I am getting `null` value for the date in my Controller. But if I use `datepicker` then I am getting the date value correctly.

```
@PostMapping("/date")
    public String addDate( @ModelAttribute("eventCreate") final EventDto eventDto){

LOG.info(" Event date ::::; "+eventDto.getEventDate());
```

`java.util.date` is the type of the `eventDate` property.

Am I missing something when using `datetimepicker`?

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, the solution was to use `th:value` instead of `th:field` in the input tag.